# Laravel change Reset Password email greeting with variable

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have an laravel 5.8 app, with the default auth installed. I want to pass a variable to the password reset email template, so the greeting would look like "Hello, [username]".
The current email template looks like this:
[image]

I didn't find where in the core files I can change this "Hello!" heading of the message

EDIT:
In my controller, I send the password reset like this(maybe the variable should be put somewhere on this line)

```
$response = Password::sendResetLink($credentials, function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });
```

Comment: Try to check `resources/views/emails`. It may not in your project, because if you're using 3rd party email provider then it may depend on their template.

Comment: `resources/views/auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a default Laravel app, the User model has a `CanResetPassword` interface with a `sendPasswordResetNotification` method. This method is created in a `CanResetPassword` trait that the user also uses.

You could override this with your own method and create your own `ResetPasswordNotification` class. Try following it from the trait to that class.

It does not look like it uses a view for the markup, so it shouldn't be too hard to do. The `ResetPassword` class takes accepts a `Notifiable`, so you should have access to the name in there.

Comment: Thanks, just added `->greeting('Hello '.$notifiable->name.'!')` in the toMail function